# Recyclerview Swipe up pagination Android

Tags: android, pagination

I am using RecyclerView with CardView in my application, I am trying to make a pagination action when user swipes to the very end of the RecyclerView and then load more if user swipes up. (Like swipe down to refresh). What I have now is when the user reach the last item of the RecyclerView it will load automatically. How can I change it so that it loads when the user pulls up?

```
    private RecyclerView.OnScrollListener recyclerViewOnScrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView,
                                     int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        if(dy > 0) //check for scroll down
        {
            visibleItemCount = gmLayoutManager.getChildCount();
            totalItemCount = gmLayoutManager.getItemCount();
            pastVisiblesItems = gmLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
            int loadedItems = pastVisiblesItems + visibleItemCount;
            //System.out.println(visibleItemCount + "/n" +totalItemCount + "/n"+pastVisiblesItems + "/n" + loadedItems);
            if (true)
            {
                if ( (visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems) >= totalItemCount)
                {
                    loading = false;
                    Log.v("...", "Last Item !");
                    //Do pagination.. i.e. fetch new data
                    String api = "stores?offset=10";
                    getData(api); //Load more data
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need to set some `onTouchListener` on parent view. And send set some variable in RecyclerView to indicate if it in the bottom. So in listener you basically do something like this:

```
if (recyclerView.isAtBottom() && motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
 //calculate some offset here
    if (offset>MY_OFFSET){
       String api = "stores?offset=10";
       getData(api); //Load more data
    }
}
```

Also you might need to fire some event from `RecyclerView` when it reaches button for your touch listener to remember pointer position at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Jerryko Checkout this sample example for Loadmore recyclerview

https://github.com/Pyush/Android-RecyclerView-Loadmore